# Inserting data into a database with an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't know why the query is not working, might be a slight error that I have missed. I'm try to insert data into a table column depending if it is a match or not. I know data is in my array but I suspect it the query I'm writing out that is giving me an error.

Here is my code:

```
$querytwo = 'INSERT INTO `' . $tablename . '` ' . ' (`' . $match_player_in_game . '`) ' . 'VALUES' . '(' . 'yes' . ')';

foreach ($player_fromsite as $match_player_in_game) {

    for ($a = 0; $a < 11; $a++) {
        if ($match_player_in_game == $home_players[$a]) {
            // Insert a row of information into the table "example"
            mysql_query($querytwo) or die(mysql_error());

        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

The message is returning `'Undefined variable: match_player_in_game'`.

Comment: You're using the variable _before_ defining it. Put the query inside the loop, not outside

Comment: you need to put your $querytwo inside the for() loop, then it will work for you

Comment: @frosty11x your comment should be an answer

Comment: ok, I see it now. I try that

Comment: I'm still receiving an error message saying Unknown column 'yes' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put your `$querytwo` inside the for() loop, then it will work for you

Comment: I'm still receiving an error message saying Unknown column 'yes' in 'field list'. do you think it is the query

Comment: The query looks fine for the most part, but I would do this instead: `'("' . 'yes' . '")';` That might fix it for you

Comment: Please use this for the query `$querytwo = "INSERT INTO \`$tablename\` (\`$match_player_in_game\`) VALUES ('yes')";`

Answer (score 0):

It should be

foreach ($player_fromsite as $match_player_in_game) {

```
   $querytwo = 'INSERT INTO `' . $tablename . '` ' . ' (`' . $match_player_in_game . '`) ' . 'VALUES' . '(' . 'yes' . ')';

  for ($a = 0; $a < 11; $a++) {
    if ($match_player_in_game == $home_players[$a]) {
        // Insert a row of information into the table "example"
        mysql_query($querytwo) or die(mysql_error());

    } else {

    }
}
```

}